# Force HTTPS / Mod-rewrite behind reverse proxy (with WordPress)

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, https, mod-proxy

Forgive my lack of knowledge in this area.

First, our situation: We have a reverse proxy setup where we have http://www.xxx.ca/x and sometimes http://www.xxx.ca/x/y is forwarded to http://xxx1a.xxx.ca/x or http://xxx1a.xxx.ca/x/y

We have been trying to create a generic .htaccess where we do not have to define any subdirectories specifically. Basically, we can use this .htaccess on 100's of sites without modifying the file on a site by site basis.

We have gotten this part working. However, we are unable to force https. Every example I see uses HTTP_HOST, which returns the value of the proxied server - not the original request.

Perhaps there is a completely different solution to what we have setup, but my knowledge of apache is limited. Below is what we currently have - which solves the generic sub-folder issue, but not the HTTPS issue.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{ENV:URI} ^$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [ENV=URI:$1]

RewriteCond %{ENV:BASE} ^$
RewriteCond %{ENV:URI}::%{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)::(.*?)\1$
RewriteRule ^ - [ENV=BASE:%2]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule . %{ENV:BASE}index.php [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

I am completely willing to change 100% of this if there is a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I have understood when you have to redirect the user to https. Anyway, when you have to switch to https, you could just check SERVER_PORT server internal variable and if is not 80 then redirect:

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{ENV:URI}/$1 [L,R=301]
```